# Custom Validation in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I want to implement custom validation (Required/Pattern/Disable) through directive in Angular 8:

```html
<input type="text"
      custom-data-annotation
      [(ngModel)]="someValue"
      name="userName" />
```

I have created the following directive:

```js
@Directive({selector: '[custom-data-annotation]'})
export class CustomDataAnnotationDirective implements OnInit  { 

  constructor(public el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) {} 

  ngOnInit() {
    this._renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'required', 'true'); 
  } 
}
```

When I run the application and inspect element I can see the `required` attribute on `input` field, but when I submit my page without putting any value in that field it always returns false for "myForm.form.invalid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a validator that works in a template-driven form control, putting a `required` attribute on the form control is not enough, because angular build its validators at compile time. At runtime, to add a validator dynamically, you'll need to tell angular that your directive is a validation one. Additionally, you must check for the control's validity by yourself. You can do these 2 things by **implementing the `Validator` interface and provide it with `NG_VALIDATORS` token** ([see the docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators)):

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[custom-data-annotation]',
  // You must provide the class with `NG_VALIDATORS` token
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: CustomDataAnnotationDirective,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CustomDataAnnotationDirective implements OnInit, Validator {
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._renderer.setAttribute(this._el.nativeElement, 'required', 'true');
  }

  // This method is demanded by the the Validator interface
  validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    return !control.value ? { required: true } : null;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma614380316433166?file=src/app/custom-data-annotation.directive.ts)

And... if it's up to you to decide it, consider switching to `ReactiveFormsModule`, as recommended by [@angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#introduction-to-forms-in-angular), for *complex forms*.